# How to use dplyr::filter with input values in a reactive environment?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I am trying to let users choose a variable in the dataset `diamonds`. Then, a checkbox group will pop up (with all the unique names in that variable). For example, if I select the "color" column of the diamonds dataset, a group of check box will appear (In this case its E, I, J, H, F, G, D). Then, users should be able to filter the dataset by colors by checking only the colors they want. However, when I use `filter` on the data, the table shows nothing apart from the header. I am wondering what is happening here, if anyone got a clue? Thanks!

MWE:

UI:

```
data("diamonds")
data1 <- diamonds
ui <-  fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("class", label = "Class", choices = c("NONE", names(data1)), selected = "NONE")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("classtype"),
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$classtype <- renderUI({
    if (input$class != "NONE") {
      checkboxGroupInput("classtype", label = "Class Type", choices = sapply(classlist(), unique))
    }
  })
  
  classlist <- reactive({
    data1 %>% 
      select(input$class)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data1 %>%
      filter(input$class %in% input$classtype)
  })
}
```

I thought `filter` will work since the server will receive input as a character vector of the selected values, according to Checkbox Group Input documentation. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: For clarification, my main purpose is to be able to filter these data and use it for multiple purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in your `filter()`. You have to pass it as a `symbol`. Try this,

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
        output$classtype <- renderUI({
                if (input$class != "NONE") {
                        checkboxGroupInput("classtype", label = "Class Type", choices = sapply(classlist(), unique))
                }
        })
        
        classlist <- reactive({
                data1 %>% 
                        select(input$class)
        })
        
        output$table <- renderTable({
                data1 %>%
                        filter(!!sym(input$class) %in% input$classtype)
        })
        
}
```

This is equivalent of the following non-`shiny` problem,

```
mtcars %>% filter("cyl" == 6)
```

Which will return an empty `data.frame`. However, if you modify it accordingly, it will give you what you are looking for,

```
mtcars %>% filter(!!sym("cyl") == 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `input$class` is just a character string with the variable name. To make your app work you could make use of e.g. the `.data` pronoun to "tell" dplyr that you mean the variable with name `input$class`. Additionally I added an `if` to make sure that your app don't breaks before a variable is chosen:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$classtype <- renderUI({
    if (input$class != "NONE") {
      checkboxGroupInput("classtype", label = "Class Type", choices = classlist())
    }
  })

  classlist <- reactive({
    unique(data1[[input$class]])
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if (input$class != "NONE") {
      data1 %>%
        filter(.data[[input$class]] %in% input$classtype)  
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Go check the package [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/): I use it when i need interactivity for tables in Shiny. This is easy to understand and it filters really well the data.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I am currently using DT as well in my app but that will certainly help me to improve mine. However, I wish to be able to filter my data based on users input and store it, so that it can be used for multiple purposes, such as plotting a graph.  I probably should clarify that in my question, my apologies.